# Oxiclean for cleaning drip machines?

Tags: drip-brew, cleaning

I have a technivorm mochamaster. The carafe browned on the inside as it is prone to do with time.  Instead of cleaning the whole machine I dumped in some Oxiclean in the carafe, filed it with water and waited.  A brown foam formed and I was left with a good as new carafe.  My question is can I run oxiclean through the machine without damaging it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use Oxyclean inside. 
That "brown foam" that you had in the carafe would be difficult to remove from the inside working without a LOT of rinse cycles.
I simply use a solution of 1/3 vinegar and 2/3 water and run that through with great results. 
I also use filtered water which helps tremendously keeping things clean.